# No access to Database File

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

Last week I created a ASP.NET Web Application project on my machine. It was connecting to a SQL server database file for testing. The database was created in the server explorer part of visual studio and it created a database file with all of the information within it. I was using windows authentication to connect to the database.

Recently my computer has been migrated onto a new netowrk within my company. Now I no longer have access to the database file. The error I am getting is `Login failed for user "DOMAIN/USER"`. I guess this is because the Domain has changed and my computer and the database server are in different domains. However I do not have access to the old domain to add a new login or user with priveladges to access the database.

How can i get arround this?

Comment: why you not change the web.config and add the new domain/user ?

Comment: Unless I'm complete missing the point (which is highly likely!) you're asking "why can't I circumvent security?". If you don't have access, you need to talk to somebody who does, who can setup the correct permissions for you to connect to the database in question.

Comment: Aristos, Changing the web.config settings will not change anything as im not trying to access the database from the application (yet) i am trying to access it through the server explorer in Visual Studio.

Comment: freefaller, I cannot ask anyone to give me permissions as no one else has access to the database. I created it as a test database when i created the project and it is just a file (.mdf) and because my domain has changed i no longer hve access. Hope this helps

Comment: Glenn, can you browse to the database in windows explorer??

Comment: (Just a side note, in order for people to receive notification that you have replied, please use the `@` character before their name, [see here for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting))

Comment: Not a problem. Where is the SQLServer hosted? If the database didn't move with you (i.e. because SQLServer is not hosted on your local machine) then I'm very surprised that there are no `sa`s who can setup access for your new domain account.

Comment: @freefaller I am the only one who has ever touched the database. No one else has had access to it ever. The database is a database file and is not hosted anywhere. In Visual Studio there is a server explorer area where you can connect to a database file (.mdf file) using the "Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient)" data source.

Comment: @larryr I can browse to the .mdf file in windows explorer yes

Comment: Fair enough @Glen, I was unaware of the ability to connect directly into a `.mdf` file through anything other than SQLServer... I will bow out of this, and hope you get a solution to your problem.  Good luck!

Comment: I may be misunderstanding this but it sounds like you have created your users with windows authentication, and now the domain has changed your users cant login since the user account on the server is for OldDoman\User and you are trying to log in with NewDoman\User. Can you not just log into the database with the SA account and then add your new users or update the old ones?

Comment: @Purplegoldfish What is the SA Account?

Comment: @GlenRobson when you setup the SQL Server you usually set a Server Admin (SA) account password.

Comment: @Purplegoldfish It didnt ask me for one when i created the database? Is this because i created it using Windows authentication? I have read that if you use this authentication it sets the SA account to disabled by default?

Comment: @GlenRobson Ah, I thought it forced you to create an SA account. Since the server is on another domain can you not remote desktop into the PC hosting it from either your or another PC on that domain?

Comment: @purplegoldfish The old domain is not on another server it is no longer available. Once the migration had finished the old server was shut down along with the old domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get around this, unless an admin is willing to give you a copy of the files from the old drive.

**So, you must re-create your database.**

Fortunately, if you took proper precautions, this will be easy.

Option 1: If your database is under source control, simply checkout the latest good version of the database.

Option 2: Load the latest backup of the database.